# How to use a heroku app inside a html iframe?

Tags: html, spring-boot, heroku, dom, iframe

I want to use this heroku app (spring boot) inside an iframe. https://sef-github-leaderboard.herokuapp.com/ but it doesn't work. it says `refused to connect`. Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://sef-github-leaderboard.herokuapp.com/" title="Iframe Example" style="height:500px;width:100%;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up devtools, click the Network tab, refresh the page, and click the first item in the waterfall, you'll find that the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) header `X-Frame-Options` is set to `DENY` on the URL you are seeking to embed. This instructs the browser to disallow loading the page within an `iframe`. To get around this, you would need to use a [forward proxy](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-a-proxy-server-works-in-node-js/) to strip out the headers.